# How to get modified relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

We have the models: Question and Answer.

In the answers table, we have a boolean column with the name `accepted` and we have just one accepted Answer. We want to get question with its answers and accept answer separately.

I use two approaches, but I don't know which is better:

1). check if the relation is loaded if loaded filter relations and get an accepted answer like this:

```
if(!$this->relationLoaded('answers')){
            $this->load('answers');
        }
        return $this->answers->firstWhere('accepted',true);
```

2). We can use this approach too:

```
function accepted_answer(){
  return $this->answer()->where('accepted',true);
}
```

The problem of the second approach is we get an array, but we expect a single response or null.
Is there any better approach to this or we can use neither 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `Accessor` on `Question` model.

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function getSelectedAnswerAttribute()
    {
        return $this->answers->where('accepted', true)->first();
    }
}
```

now in every `Answer` instance has an attribute called `selected_answer`.

You can access it like,

```
$answer->selected_answer;
```

**Note**

this 'selected_answer' is not fetching from database, it filters from already fetched answers list. so its more efficient than your 2nd approach.

and, If you want this attribute automatically bind to the `Question` model always. add this `accessor` to `appends` array.

**Model**

```
protected $appends = ['selected_answer'];
```

Comment: What you are doing here is querying for all answers and then filtering them with `where` which can be a performance hit if there is a lot of answers/questions. But I will upvote because of the general approach with `appends`

Comment: But only when the 'selected_answer' is called. when he calls it, he has already fetch all the answers using `with()` eager loading. That was my point

Comment: That is true, but what if he doesn't call `load('answers')` before doing `selected_answer`? You should just edit the post and instead of doing `->answers` do `->with(['answers' => function($query) {return $query->where('accepted', true);}])`

Comment: In your commented answer it query to the database again. It's a big performance hit. That what i wanted to avoid. In his question he has specified "We want to get question with its answers and accept answer separately. " That means he wants both 'all answers' ans 'the selected answer' so why query to the database again when we have the selected answer in the fetched data.?

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the **second** approach as you will have a single source to change later on if something changes (instead of digging through a lot of controllers)

To get the result, use `->get();` at the end of builder query.

P.S: [Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes) are generally always better than writing queries manually inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

create `accepted` scope at your `answer` model.

```
public function scopeAccepted($query){
   return $query->where("accepted",true)->first();
}
```

then you can easly retreive first accepted answer.

```
$question->answer()->accepted();
```

for more further check out [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes);